# Accessing WidgetKit IntentTimelineProvider from main app target SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, widgetkit

I'm trying to access `IntentTimelineProvider` of `WidgetExtension` from the main app. I'm doing this so that I can get the date property from the `IntentTimelineProvider` and use it in a view in the main app target as you can see from the below code.

I have set the target membership of the files(file in the main app target and the file in the widget extension target) to both App and Widget.

**Widget Extension**

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import Intents

struct Provider: IntentTimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: ConfigurationIntent())
    }

    func getSnapshot(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: configuration)
        completion(entry)
    }

//build time error here: "Reference to invalid associated type 'Entry' of type 'Provider'" here...
    func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        var entries = [SimpleEntry]()
        let currentDate = Date()
        let midnight = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: currentDate)
        let nextMidnight = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: midnight)!

        for offset in 0 ..< 60 * 24 {
           let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: offset, to: midnight)!
            entries.append(SimpleEntry(date: entryDate, configuration: configuration))
        }

        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .after(nextMidnight))
        completion(timeline)
    }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let configuration: ConfigurationIntent
}

struct TimeWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        NotingView(entry: entry)
    }
}

@main
struct TimeWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "TimeWidget"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        IntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: ConfigurationIntent.self, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            TimeWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("My Widget")
        .description("This is an example widget.")
    }
}

struct TimeWidget_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TimeWidgetEntryView(entry: SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: ConfigurationIntent()))
            .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemSmall))
    }
}
```

[image]

---

**Main App**

```
import SwiftUI

struct SampleView: View {
    var entry : Provider.Entry
    var body: some View {
        Text(entry.date, style: .time)
    }
}
```

[image]

I'm currently getting the build time error :
"
Reference to invalid associated type 'Entry' of type 'Provider'
"
at `getTimeline()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main app, use `SimpleEntry` instead of `Provider.Entry`. The latter is referencing the associated type of your implementation of the `TimelineProvider` protocol, but for whatever reason the app can’t infer the type (maybe somebody more Swift-savvy than me can explain). But you don’t need to infer it, just give it the actual type: `SimpleEntry`.

```
struct SampleView: View {
    var entry : SimpleEntry
    var body: some View {
        Text(entry.date, style: .time)
    }
}
```